# C++ Method chaining with classes

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, method-chaining

I'm attempting to do method chaining, however, instead of using the Methods in "Foo" I want to a constructor of a class (which is inherited from the base class):

```
class Bar {

public: 

Bar() {
    std::cout << "This is bar";
}

 };

 class Foo : public Bar {

    public:
    Foo() {
        cout << "This is foo";
    }
 };
```

So my main would look like the following:

`Foo f = Foo().Bar();`

Why is this not possible in C++/C++11? Also, is there a way in which I can integrate this standard, or would I have to create an method in "Foo" which calls the constructor to "Bar"?

Edit:

```
class Bar {
public: 
Bar() {
}

Bar& Options() {
    cout << "sf";
    return *this;
}
 };

class Foo : public Bar {

public:
    Foo() {

    }
  };
```

And then in main:

`Foo F = Foo().Options();`

Comment: Why do you want to do that? A call to `Foo()` already calls `Bar()`.

Comment: @juanchopanza Sorry for the confusion, please see my edit and this is what I would like to do.. Is this possible?

Comment: You can do `Foo F; F.Options();` or `Foo().Options()` - but not both in one line.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I really want/need this to be method chained. mhm. Is there no way to do this?

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish? Not the chaining stuff, but the underlying problem. As is, this is an X-Y problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your updated question is illegal because `Bar::Options()` returns a reference to a `Bar` and you don't provide a way to convert a `Bar` to a `Foo` object.

Comment: He could have Bar::Options return a Foo& using CRTP.

Comment: @FrançoisMoisan - All of my compilers complain about being unable to convert from Bar& to Foo. That's why I phrased the answer the way I did. Yes, he could have used CRTP. That's an advanced topic. Do you think the questioner knows what that means?

Comment: @DavidHammen Thanks. and Francois - I will attempt to use CRTP and see where that get's me :)

Comment: @David Hammen I was merely suggesting the alternative. It was nothing against your comment.