# C++ calling objects from another class

Tags: c++, oop

I asked this question here: [C++ Method chaining with classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725072/c-method-chaining-with-classes)

In essesance, what I am trying to do is call a Constructor/Method from another class using Method chaining. Let's say I have 2 classes:

```
class Signal {

    public:
      Signal() { } // constructor

      Signal& ParseSignal() { 

          // In this method I want to call 
          // the constructor "Parse()" 
      }

    protected:
       std::vector<double> data;
};
```

And I have another class called `Parse`:

```
class Parse {

   public:

      Parse() {
        // This is the implementation
        // I need to access the "data" contained in class "Signal

};
```

My main objective would be to do the following in main:

```
Signal s = Signal().ParseSignal();
```

This would then accept the signal, and, Parse this.

Someone suggested that I should use `CRTP` however, due to the fact that the base class (in this case `Signal`) has to have a `template<>` argument, this is not possible due to other classes inheriting.

Is there another solution to this problem?

EDIT:

I have tried the following, however, it looks like a `dirty` implementation and I cannot access the member variable:

```
class Parser {

public:

    Parser() { 
        parse();    
    }

    void parse() {
        cout << "YES";
    }
 };

 class Signal {

public:
    friend class Parser; 
    Signal() { val = 0;}

    Signal& Parse() {
        Parser::Parser();
        return *(this);
    }
protected:

    int val;

 };
```

Comment: You mean `new Signal()`? Or is `Signal()` a global function?

Comment: @crush So it would be `new Signal()` Sorry, my bad.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that in your actual code there are arguments to some of these functions? If not, it seems like the `Signal` constructor could just construct a `Parse` object and do whatever it needs to do with it to create the `Signal` object.

Comment: Are you opposed to letting Signal inherit from Parser? That way you would have access to it's methods

Comment: I see you tried making Parser a friend of Signal. Why were you unable to access `data` when `data` is protected? That should work, I think?

Comment: So, let me get this straight. You want to be able to do: `Signal s = new Signal().Parse();`? That doesn't seem to fit your design. I think you should do `Signal s = new Signal(new Parser());`

Comment: How will `Parser` know what type of data it is parsing? Are you going to have sub classes of `Parser`? There are still a lot of question marks about what/how you are accomplishing this.

Comment: @crush - That could work, however, what should therefore the constructor be in `Signal` to allow for a new constructor to `Parser` to be passed in?

Comment: @crush Basically, when `.Parse()` is used, the method inside `Signal` calls the constructor in `Parse` which then executes all of the functions inside the class.

Comment: Well, I'm confused because at the top of your question, `Signal` has a `std::vector<double> data` and at the bottom, `Signal` has a `int val`. Does it have one or the other? Both? Do you mean to have different types of signals, like `class IntegerSignal : public Signal<int>`?

Comment: @crush No, no, sorry! The second example (in the `edit`) was just a test function and therefore, the data that Signal will hold is a `std::vector<double>` and that's it. Nothing else :)

Comment: What you're trying to do here is: `Signal s; s.Parse()` but in a single statement, yes? The code you've written looks closer to `Signal temp; temp.Parse(); s = temp;`.

Comment: @kfsone Yes :)! And if I do `Signal temp; temp.Parse();` it calls the constructor in the class `Parse` . Does this make sense?

Comment: Wait - you are trying to call Parser's constructor from inside Signal? You can't do that without creating a parser. `Parser p;`.

Comment: Can you explain what `Parser.Parse()` is supposed to do to the `data`?

Comment: A constructor is for the purpose of handling creation of an object. Co-opting it for other purposes is just bad design. If you're not creating a Parser object, don't call it.

Comment: @kfsone So the simplest solution to this problem would just be to create a new `Parser p` inside of the class `Signal` and within the function `ParseSignal` just initialise it? I think i got it :)

Comment: `Signal s = new Signal(new Parser()).Parse();` I'd dependency inject it like this, but you can create it inside the class too if you know you will never want to have more than 1 parser. You could also create an instance of `Parser` on the stack each time `Parse()` is called, so you don't have to worry about memory leaks.

Comment: @crush Thanks for that. But, what would the constructor in `Signal` need to be in order to pass a `new Parser()` in?

Comment: `Signal(Parser* parser);` Then store it in a pointer member. Don't forget to clean it up when either `Signal` is destructed, or when it is no longer needed elsewhere (if it is shared for example). That can get tricky, that is why I suggested making it on the stack in the `Parse()` method.

Comment: None of this discussion helps with you accessing `data`, but you should be able to access it if `Parser` is a friend class and `data` is protected.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++: How to call a parent class function from derived class function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357307/c-how-to-call-a-parent-class-function-from-derived-class-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You implicitly cannot and should not do what you appear to be trying to do, which is to call the constructor of a class without constructing an instance of the class.

If you want the behavior of Parser in Signal, then you have at least three options: 1. Inherit Parser, 2. Add a Parser member, 3. Create a "Parseable" interface-class which Parser can take as an argument.

```
class Parser {
public:
    class Interface {
    public:
        std::vector<double> m_data;
    };

    Parser(Interface& interface) {
        parse(interface);
    }
};


class SignalInheriting : public Parser::Interface {
public:
    SignalInheriting() {
        Parser p(*this); // can take the Parser::Interface view of this object.
    }
};

class SignalMember {
    Parser::Interface m_parserIface;
public:
    SignalMember() : m_parserIface() {
    }
};
```

Doing heavy lifting in constructors like this is great for obfuscated or dog-show code, but is terrible for production systems that require any kind of maintenance.

But if you're fine with having to diagnose problems in code that works hands-free like this at 3am on a Saturday when you're hung over - then go for it.

A major factor to which pattern you should choose is how long the parse-related data is going to persist vs how long the Signal objects are going to persist.

Conversely, if the Signal object is little more than a specialization of the "Parse" API, then just inherit Parse and be done with.

Comment: I like this idea. Programming to an interface, and basically employing the visitor pattern.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do what you are trying to do would be something like this:

```
class Parse {
public:
    Parse(std::vector<double> &data) {
        // do stuff
    }
};

class Signal {
public:
    Signal() { } // constructor

    Signal& ParseSignal() { 
        Parse parser(data);
        return *this;
    }

protected:
    std::vector<double> data;
};
```

However I suggest that you take a look at the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) for a more generic solution.

Or at the very least don't do the work in the Parse constructor, do it in some method instead.

Comment: Wouldn't that be `Parse parser(*data)`?

Comment: @crush No, the constructor is taking a reference.

Comment: and you are passing it a value?

Comment: @crush No, again, it's a non-const reference so you can actually even change the data if you like.

Comment: Hmmm, if you say so. Been awhile since I've done any C++ =/ Java is ruining me.

Comment: @crush `std::vector<double> &data` is the argument that Parse takes, i.e. a reference.

Comment: Yes, I get that. But it seems to me like the `data` member itself is not a reference, and you'd need to dereference it?

Comment: @crush, you should refresh your understanding of C++ before trying this. The reference binds to `data` (references don't only bind to references) and you don't need to dereference it. Maybe you're confusing references and pointers.

Comment: @crush That's right, that's how passing references works. No need for `&` in the call or `*` in the function. Given a function `void f(int &x)`, you can not write `f(1)` because `1` is not a variable and f expects a reference.

Comment: Ah, no, references are pointers with a contract so that you can use them like instances within the scope the reference exists. `int i = 1; int& j = i; j = 2;` changes the value of i.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I think you're right. Time to do some refresher exercises. Sheesh. Thanks fellas.